# React native Expo-AV looping sound for specific second

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, expo-av

I am building a application where its required to play a background music when user enters a specific page for certain amount of time. I am using expo-av for the sound and looping the sound while createAsync as `{islooping:true}` and passing the **playSound** function in **useEffect**

My question is, Is there any way i can set the looping for certain amount of seconds? Like after looping will be off and sound will be stop after the amount of seconds.

Been through expo documentation, couldnt find anything helpful. Please Help.

Comment: Can you use a `setTimeout` to stop the sound after the set amount of time?